# python-ldap add member to Active Directory group

Tags: active-directory, python

I am trying to add member to Active Directory group with script using python-ldap module. Here are my attempt so far:

```
import ldap
from ldap import modlist as modlist

l = ldap.initialize(server)
l.simple_bind_s(username, password)
l.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRAL)

old_members = new_members = dict()
new_members['member'] = 'cn=Forename Name,ou=Users,dc=DOMAIN'
old_members
group_dn = 'cn=GROUP,ou=Groups,dc=DOMAIN'

try:
    ldif = modlist.modifyModlist(old_members,new_members)
    l.modify_s(group_dn, ldif)
except ldap.LDAPError,e:
    print e
```

I got this error: `LdapError: DSID-0C090C48, comment: Error in attribute conversion`

I have no idea where does this error comes from, after having searched Google up and down.

I would be really happy having a hint, or an other way to add user to group, which should be quite a common task from python-ldap

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was looking at your code, and I think this line creates two pointers to the same dictionary:

old_members = new_members = dict()

This would cause the ldif object to be equal to [] when you run this line:

ldif = modlist.modifyModlist(old_members,new_members)

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
old_members = new_members = dict()
```

to

```
old_members = dict()
new_members = dict()
new_members['member'] = 'cn=Forename Name,ou=Users,dc=DOMAIN'
```

I tested that it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM
from elizabeth import Personal, Address,Text
from ldap3.extend.microsoft.addMembersToGroups import ad_add_members_to_groups as addUsersInGroups
import random

serverName='dc1.stand.local'
connUser="stand.lsd\\Admin"
connUserPwd=""
usersOU = 'ou=test-ou,dc=stand,dc=local'
groupsOU = 'ou=test-groups,dc=stand,dc=local'

usersDnList = []
groupsDnList = []

server = Server(serverName, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user=connUser, password=connUserPwd, authentication=NTLM)
conn.bind() #must be TRUE

conn.add(usersOU, 'organizationalUnit') # add test-ou for users
conn.add(groupsOU, 'organizationalUnit') # add test-ou for groups

data = Text('en')
for _ in range(0,10):
    currentGroup = 'cn='+data.word()+',ou=test-groups,dc=stand,dc=local'
    groupsDnList.append(currentGroup)
    conn.add(currentGroup, 'group')

address = Address('en')
person = Personal('en')
for _ in range(0,10):
    address_country = address.country()
    conn.add('ou='+address_country+',ou=test-ou,dc=stand,dc=local', 'organizationalUnit')
    for _ in range (0,10):
        name = person.name(gender='male')
        surname = person.surname(gender='male')
        currentUser = 'cn='+name+'.'+surname+','+'ou='+address_country+',ou=test-ou,dc=stand,dc=local'
        usersDnList.append(currentUser)
        conn.add(currentUser, 'User',
        {'givenName': name,
        'sn': surname,
        'departmentNumber': 'DEV',
        'telephoneNumber': 1111})

for _ in range(0,300):
    rndUser = random.choice(usersDnList)
    rndGroup = random.choice(groupsDnList)
    addUsersInGroups(conn, rndUser, rndGroup)
```

Comment: try improving formatting and answer please